# Best way to center align a div with unknown width and height?

Tags: html, css, css-expressions

Say I have a div on my page as:

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

My CSS looks something like:

```
.center{
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left: ?
    margin-top: ?
}
```

So as you can see above, the only thing that I need to know is how to set `margin-left` and `margin-top` values. If I had a known width and height of `.center` div (say 300px each), I would have set `margin-left` and `margin-top` values as half of that value (-150px both)

But my question is how do I set those values if width/height of `.center` div is unknown (or say it's dynamic)?

Can I use some kind of CSS expression OR does that have cross-browser limitations? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you mean horizontal and vertical: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Comment: With a little jQuery this becomes very easy. Is jQuery an option?

Comment: CSS expressions are only supported by IE5/6/7. They were discontinued as of IE8, and were never supported by non-IE browsers.

Answer (score 4):

To center horizontally is pretty easy. Use

```
width: 50%; /* or anything other than auto */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

or alternatively:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

To center vertically, it's a bit more difficult, and depends a lot on the other elements surrounding your div. See [this article](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) for some pointers.

Comment: I do not have any container element....Just the div to be center...So I do not want to use the auto technique...

Comment: @testndtv why not? It's by far the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @MattCoughlin it works with proportional width too. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tKeEN/)

Comment: Clarification: `margin: auto` only works with an explicit (non-auto) width (a length value, such as px, em, or %). In this case, there's no explicit width.

Comment: @MattCoughlin point taken. I included a note about that in my answer

Comment: The asker is specifically asking about unknown widths. 50% is not an unknown width. This is not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest version of this pattern.

```
 .center-block
 {     
      margin: 0 auto
 }
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rjY7F/482/, which also works if there are multiple elements that need to be centered regardless of screen size. (question is the case with only one element)

Comment: You are just repeating what we all know doesn't work, even the author acknowledged that this doesn't work. This does not answer anything. In the example in the comments, you are setting explicit widths. If the author of the question knew the width, this question would never have been asked. This answer does not help at all.

Answer (score 3):

If your div hasn't a fixed size, unfortunately the only way is to use javascript.

For example [(jsFiddle Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/LAEqq):

Javascript(jQuery)

```
var $container = $('#centered');

var mLeft = $container.outerWidth() / 2;
var mTop = $container.outerHeight() / 2;

$container.css({
    'margin-left': -mLeft, 
    'margin-top': -mTop,
});
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With no explicit width, no ancestor elements to make use of, and only a single div, the only option left may be to use JavaScript or jQuery (if that's an option).

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/nCLJR/) using jQuery (dynamically set the margin).

**CSS**

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var leftOffset = $('.center').width() >> 1;
var topOffset = $('.center').height() >> 1;
$('.center').css('margin', '-' + topOffset + 'px 0 0 -' + leftOffset + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make div center of the page. Width property must be set.

```
.center{
   background:red;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width:500px;
}
```